# Marklogic 8 - a schedule task error err:FOTY0013 Functions cannot be atomized

Tags: marklogic

The query is successfully working on qconsole. But setup a schedule task. it spool out errors err:FOTY0013 Functions cannot be atomized...

```
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at 
 "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

  xdmp:set-request-time-limit(3600),
  let $custom :=
  let $config := json:config("custom")
  let $_ := map:put($config,"whitespace","ignore")
  let $_ := map:put($config,"array-element-names","TR")
  return $config
  let $res := cts:uris(..code..)
 for $uri in $res
 (..code..)
 let $_ := if(xdmp:filesystem-file-exists($dirPath))
    then ()
    else xdmp:filesystem-directory-create(
        $dirPath,
        <options xmlns="xdmp:filesystem-directory-create">
            <create-parents>true</create-parents>
        </options>
    )
let $_ := xdmp:save(
    fn:concat($dirPath,$accStr,".json"),
    json:transform-to-json(fn:doc($uri),$custom)
)
```

in a schedule task spool out error err:FOTY0013 Functions cannot be atomized...

```
2019-01-03 13:52:00.180 Notice: TaskServer:   $custom = map:map(<map:map 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC: 
(err:FOTY0013) Functions cannot be atomized...)
2019-01-03 13:52:00.180 Notice: TaskServer:   $dtfmt = "20190103"
2019-01-03 13:52:00.180 Notice: TaskServer:   $sdate1 = "2018-12- 
27T13:52:00.175667-05:00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC) can occur when producing the error log message as it attempts to generate the error message and serialize the content of a variable that is, or contains functions. The `$json:config` has several properties that are functions, and it can't atomize the `$json:config` to print out the content of that variable in the error log message, as you can see that it had done for the `$dtfmt` and `$sdate1` variables.

[Atomization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-atomization)

> The result of atomization is either a sequence of atomic values or a [type error](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-type-error) [err:FOTY0012].
>
> Definition: Atomization of a sequence is defined as the result of invoking the `fn:data` function on the sequence, as defined in [[XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators (Second Edition)]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#FunctionsAndOperators).

You can observe the same error by executing this code in QConsole:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at 
 "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $custom :=
  let $config := json:config("custom")
  let $_ := map:put($config,"whitespace","ignore")
  let $_ := map:put($config,"array-element-names","TR")
  return $config

return $custom
```

You haven't provided enough of the code or the error message to tell for sure, but **XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC** is not likely the root cause of your issue. Look further up in the error log for the start of the exception to see what the real error is. It should have the module and line number.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more info like a minimal reproducible full example.
You might try adding the XQuery version in the prolog to force your QCOnsole code and task code to run the same xquery version,  I believe the defaults are different.

Comment: The problem solved.  the query looks for the collation cts:field-range-query("crd", "<", $sdate1) that inside  cts:uris(..code..).  Thanks